# Applying adaptive thresholding to inrange function opencv c++

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

I want to take a video and create a binary from it, I want it so that if the pixel is within a certain range it will be included within the binary. In other words I want an upper and lower bound like in the `inRange()` function as opposed to a simple cutoff point like in the `threshold()` function.

I also want to use adaptive thresholding to account for differences in lighting in my video. Is there a way to do this? I know there is `inRange()` that does the former and `adaptiveThreshold()` that does the latter, but I don't know if there is a way to do both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply adaptiveThreshold() to the whole original image, then apply inRange() to the original image and use the result of inRange() as a mask:

```
adaptiveThreshold(original_image, dst_image ... );
inRange(original_image, minArray, maxArray, mask);
Mat output = dst_image.mul(mask);
```